# Windows fatal exception: access violation \ Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, pycharm

I am trying to debug a Python program named 'RTSPbrute' using faulthandler and PyCharm.

https://gitlab.com/woolf/RTSPbrute/

I receive the error message...

> Windows fatal exception: access violation

...using the command prompt, and...

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

...from PyCharm.

I already have logged the Queue from different code locations, where the error is apparently.
Logged the threads...almost everything that is printable.
Debugging step by step for days using Pycharm. Unfortunately I can't find the bug(s).
Strangely enough, the error message keeps appearing at different times, even though i use the same input. Which makes me think the error is Windows or Python related as i often read.
there is a lot of information about the exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005), but i have not found a working one.

Does anyone know a solution, missing package, maybe better debugging techniques?

The faulthandler output.

```
Thread 0x00002274 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Update\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\colorama\win32.py", line 105 in GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo
  File "C:\Users\Update\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\colorama\winterm.py", line 150 in erase_line
  File "C:\Users\Update\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 235 in call_win32
  File "C:\Users\Update\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 202 in convert_ansi
  File "C:\Users\Update\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 188 in write_and_convert
  File "C:\Users\Update\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 162 in write
  File "C:\Users\Update\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 41 in write
  File "C:\Users\Update\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\rich\console.py", line 1932 in _check_buffer
  File "C:\Users\Update\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\rich\console.py", line 800 in _exit_buffer
  File "C:\Users\Update\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\rich\console.py", line 842 in __exit__
  File "C:\Users\Update\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\rich\live.py", line 231 in refresh
  File "C:\Users\Update\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\rich\live.py", line 32 in run
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 966 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x0000240c (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 320 in wait
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\queue.py", line 171 in get
  File "C:\Users\Update\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\rtspbrute\modules\worker.py", line 50 in screenshot_targets
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946 in run
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 966 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x000025e4 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Update\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\rtspbrute\modules\attack.py", line 137 in get_screenshot
  File "C:\Users\Update\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\rtspbrute\modules\attack.py", line 186 in get_screenshot
  File "C:\Users\Update\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\rtspbrute\modules\worker.py", line 54 in screenshot_targets
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946 in run
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 966 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x0000395c (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 320 in wait
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\queue.py", line 171 in get
  File "C:\Users\Update\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\rtspbrute\modules\worker.py", line 50 in screenshot_targets
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946 in run
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 966 in _bootstrap
  ...
```

> Python 3.10.1 (tags/v3.10.1:2cd268a, Dec  6 2021, 19:10:37) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: Upgrading Python to `Python 3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32` didn't help. I'm going to try the 32 bit version now.

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue. Have you found out the cause or a fix for this?